# "Error: connect ENOENT" when node express middleware makes a POST request (using node request library)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-request

A node app is throwing this error when an HTTP POST request is made by our node express middleware using request library (error present only in a particular node app, no issues in others apps on the same machine using the middleware).

When external POST request is made (by middleware) to "http://outsite.com/requestData", POST doesn't work and error comes as "Error: connect ENOENT /requestData".

Code throwing error:

```
var requestLib = require('request');
var url = "http://httpbin.org/post";
var reqOptions = {
    uri: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/text"
    },
    timeout: 100000,
    body: encodeURIComponent("Testing"),
    forever: true, //keepalive
};
requestLib(reqOptions, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post the contents of reqOptions before the call. Is requestLib just `require('request');` ?

Comment: @bolav Thank you. Updated the question,  var requestLib = require('request');

Comment: I have tried your code and its working fine here.

Comment: Here is the body - {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "Testing", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "7", 
    "Content-Type": "application/text", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "1.22.85.118", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}

Comment: @harisankarh: This example runs fine on my machine. What is reqOptions when it fails? Does this script fail with ENOENT on your computer?

Comment: Tushar and bolav , Thanks for your inputs. Following answer by @ggentzke fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this issue on multiple machines.  Running the identical code snippet you provided I found POSTs worked fine when using `request@2.69.0` but consistently failed with `Error: ENOENT` for `request@2.51.0` and various other minor versions < 2.69.

I suggest updating your package.json with the following to fix this issue:
`"request": "~2.69.0"`.

Hope this helps - I was really scratching my head at inconsistent behavior across applications for a while.